# VideoView - no video but sound when played

Tags: android, mobile-development

Im newbie at android development. Trying to create a working video player but get errors. When click on a play button there is only sound no video and black screen. Tried some suggested solutions - nothing help. Here's the code:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button btn;
        VideoView videoView;
        MediaController mediaController;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vdView);
            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
            mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        }

        public void startVideo(View view) {
            String filePath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName()+ "/" + R.raw.cartoon;
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(filePath);
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    videoView.start();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Errors in console:

```
D/MediaPlayer: getMetadata
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
D/VideoView: Error: 1,-38
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
D/VideoView: Error: 1,-38
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
D/VideoView: Error: 1,-38
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f889b45a660: ver 2 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f889b45a660: ver 2 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f889b45a660: ver 2 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f889b45a660: ver 2 0
I/Choreographer: Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

HOW TO FIX IT?

Comment: try to add this in your startVideo() : videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);

Comment: Hi! I tried that, the same problem

Comment: please try with this videoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Comment: paste your videoview xml code

Comment: Sudheesh R, tried that also - no positive result. I've just changed my source video and it's started to play but only first 3 sec then again the error "can't play this video". And also the error "MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)" is gone, now I have another one "MediaPlayer: Error (100,0)".

Comment: xml:

`<VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vdView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="226dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/startBtn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.060000002" />`

Comment: try to add some width to your videoview manually and get rid of constarints for this test. Im on your mediaplayer error now. also your video is on main thread i think.

Comment: Deleted all constraints - all the same.

Comment: ok, im trying out your code. let me check.

Comment: So, I played a video of size 29MB with length 2.24 min. I found no problem. Are you checking this on emulator or actual device?

Comment: emulator, going to check on my device now

Comment: good, then its the problem of openGL settings in your emulator. Try to update your emulator to latest.